# Loop and get value of localstorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have followed this example:
https://www.sitepoint.com/quick-tip-persist-checkbox-checked-state-after-page-reload/ from @jhibbard

This is working fine but now I struggle to work with the data saved in the localstorage. I get the following ‘object’ or ‘array’:

```
{
  "checkbox1": false,
  "checkbox2": false,
  "checkbox3": false,
  "checkbox4": true,
  "checkbox5": false,
  "checkbox6": true,
  "checkbox7": false,
  "checkbox8": false,
  "checkbox9": false
}
```

This was created with following code:

```
var checkboxValues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('checkboxValues')) || {};
var $checkboxes = $("#checkbox-container :checkbox");

$checkboxes.on("change", function() {
    $checkboxes.each(function() {
        checkboxValues[this.id] = this.checked;
    });
    localStorage.setItem("checkboxValues", JSON.stringify(checkboxValues));
});

$.each(checkboxValues, function(key, value) {
    $("#" + key).prop('checked', value);
});
```

And I would like to loop over it to get every key which has the value true. I have tried this:

```
for (var i = 0, len = localStorage.length; i < len; i++) {
    var key = localStorage.key(i);
    console.log("Clef", key);
    var value = localStorage[key];
    if (value == true) console.log(key + " => " + value);
}
```

But this is returning only the name Clef checkboxValues and the test if(value==true) is not working. How should I proceed?

Comment: Why do you try to loop over `localStorage` if you just wrote a **single** item to it?

Comment: You should be attempting to get the `checkboxValues` entry from your localStorage first, e.g. `localStorage.getItem('checkboxValues')` and then iterate over it.

Comment: @NicoHaase ok this is a single item but as you can see there is few data inside that i want to sort as i explain i want to see witch key have the value true.

Comment: @Terry ok i tried this but return in console is the same. var test=localStorage.getItem('checkboxValues');
console.log("TEST",test); and then the lenght returned is 161......so it's counting the string every characteres of the array...

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. "Few data inside" refers to the **one** object in your LocalStorage, doesn't it?

Comment: @NicoHaase Sorry i am not professional and the syntaxe of programming  is sometimes hard for me ;). I am doing this as a personnal project. So my objet named 'checkboxValues' is a single object with an array inside with a pair of [key,value] and so i try to count how many key i have inside and then collect all key with value=true. So in my example, the checkbox 4 and 6 are true and i want to use this one for a sql request

Comment: I think i have to use something like this : Then when you want to retrieve data, you need to parse the string to object again.

var getObj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('item'));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get this answer and this is working:

```
const STORAGE_KEY_NAME = 'checkboxValues';
 
const storageBoxes = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('checkboxValues')) ?? {}
 
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(storageBoxes)) {
  if (value === true) {
    console.log(`Case "${key}" true !`);
    //data.append("${key}");
  }
}
```